# Opening a .sln file brings up a blank VS page

Tags: c#, file

I've looked around and the closest I have found was a problem in VS2010, this is in VS2012 Express.
Not much to say other than [image: http://imgur.com/B8KWTKW] thanks

Comment: I'm failing to see what the problem is, other than your solution explorer being 1" high so you can't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the bar beneath your solution explorer down so you can see more of the window, you will then be able to choose a file to look at.

[image]

Comment: Alright thanks, though http://imgur.com/grCbpW0 happened. sorry, probably very noobish question though this has never happened to me.

Comment: Looks like you closed the sidebar, Simpelist solutton, go to `Tools` in the menu bar, then choose `Import and Export Settings...`, then in the window that comes up choose `Reset all settings`, this will reset your UI to the default. You can also make sidebars re-appear indvidually by going to the `View` item in the menubar. For example, the thing you closed was the "Solution Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of the screen, you will see "Soultion Explorer". Expand it so you can see projects and files in the current solution. Click on the file you wish to open. It should open up.